# foreach results on the same line

Tags: php, html, css

I have this code:

```
    foreach ($ck as $k) {
         if (substr ($k, 0, 1) == '_')
         {   // skip keys starting with '_'
             continue;
         }
         $cv = get_post_custom_values($k, $post_id );  //Array

            foreach ($cv as $c) {
                if (empty ($c))
                {   // skip empty value
                    continue;
                }
                $format_c =  $c;

                print_r ('<div style="font-size: 14px;">'.$k .': '. $format_c . ' / </div>');

            }
    }

?>
```

but the result is like this:

```
something: result /
something: result /
something: result /
```

How can I change the code to have:

```
something: result / something: result / something: result /
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Don't put it in a `<div>`

Comment: Change the CSS of the DIV so it's `display: inline`.

Comment: @TheCodesee The formatting is messed up, the first set of 3 results should have newlines in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) is a block level element. Use an inline element like `<span>` instead.

```
    foreach ($ck as $k) {
         if (substr ($k, 0, 1) == '_')
         {   // skip keys starting with '_'
             continue;
         }
         $cv = get_post_custom_values($k, $post_id );  //Array

            foreach ($cv as $c) {
                if (empty ($c))
                {   // skip empty value
                    continue;
                }
                $format_c =  $c;

                echo "<span style='font-size: 14px;'>$k: $format_c / </span><br/>";

            }
    }

?>
```

Also, I don't think `print_r()` does what you think it does. [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) or [`print`](http://php.net/print) are used to output text.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($ck as $k) {
     if (substr ($k, 0, 1) == '_')
     {   // skip keys starting with '_'
         continue;
     }
     $cv = get_post_custom_values($k, $post_id );  //Array

      echo '<div style="display: inline; font-size: 14px;">';
        foreach ($cv as $c) {
            if (empty ($c))
            {   // skip empty value
                continue;
            }
            $format_c =  $c;

            print_r ($k .': '. $format_c . ' /);

        }echo '</div>';
}
```

?>